# In R How to create data frame from Read values from stdin

Tags: r

How to read the below stdin values and create a data frame in R. Here stdin values are dynamic

```
PrimeSuperMarket
4
Choclate
Jam
Milk
Rice
```

**Line 1** denotes ShopName

**Line 2** denotes NumberOfItems Planning to purchase

**Line 3 to 7** : Item Type

Line No 3 to n is dynamic that depends upon line no 2 value. If value is passed as 5 in line 2. Line 3 to Line 8 will be there, So totally 5 values will be entered.

My Expected output is

[image]

Comment: How do you get the stdin values? Where do you store them?

Comment: Hi Ronak..I have raised this question internally. but assuming if it is from text file. Any hint on how to convert that into a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file is called `input.txt` you can read it with `readLines` and create a dataframe like so -

```
val <- readLines('input.txt')
shopName <- val[1]
Item <- val[3:(3 + as.numeric(val[2]) - 1)]
# Or you can read everything removing 1st 2 values
#Item <- val[-c(1:2)]
data.frame(shopName, Item)


#          shopName     Item
#1 PrimeSuperMarket Choclate
#2 PrimeSuperMarket      Jam
#3 PrimeSuperMarket     Milk
#4 PrimeSuperMarket     Rice
```